# Mongoose aggregate returning unwanted empty array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have two models; one for the *User* and the other one for the *StudyGroup*. Each *StudyGroup* has a unique `guid` field. The *User* model has a field of studyGroups that is an array of strings `guid`. A user can join multiple study groups.

*User* model

```
 const userSchema = new Schema({
  cuid: { type: 'String', required: true },
  firstName: { type: 'String', required: true },
  lastName: { type: 'String', required: true },
  studentId: { type: 'Number', required: true },
  password: { type: 'String', required: true },
  email: { type: 'String', required: true },
  dateAdded: { type: 'Date', default: Date.now, required: true },
  lastLogin: { type: 'Date', default: null, required: false },
  studyGroups: [{ type: 'String' }],
});
```

*StudyGroup* model

```
const studyGroupSchema = new Schema({
  guid: { type: 'String', required: true },
  groupName: { type: 'String', required: true },
  course: { type: 'String', required: true },
  teacher: { type: 'String', required: true },
  description: { type: 'String', required: true },
  dateAdded: { type: 'Date', default: Date.now, required: true },
  chatMessages: [{ type: 'String' }],
});
```

I want to find all studyGroups in the `studyGroup` array of the *User* model using the strings `guid` stored inside the array. Then send the corresponding studyGroup objects to the Front-end.

```
export function getUserStudyGroups(req, res) {
  User.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$studyGroups" },
    {
      "$lookup": {
        "from": "studyGroups",
        "localField": "studyGroups",
        "foreignField": "cuid",
        "as": "resultingStudyGroupsArray"
      }
    },
    { "$unwind": "$resultingStudyGroupsArray" },
    {
      "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "myStudyGroups": { "$addToSet": "$resultingStudyGroupsArray" },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
      }
    }
  ]).exec(function(err, results){
    console.log(results);
    return res.json({ studyGroups: results });
  });
}
```

However, the code above just returns me an empty array. But I want to return an array of studyGroup objects.

Comment: `resultingTagsArray` you haven't created resulting tags array anywhere. What is it?

Comment: woops, I forgot to change that. Let me see if that was the problem.

Comment: Still empty array after changing the `resultingTagsArray` to `resultingStudyGroupsArray`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`foreignField` should be `guid`.

```
export function getUserStudyGroups(req, res) {   User.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$studyGroups" },
    {
      "$lookup": {
        "from": "studyGroups",
        "localField": "studyGroups",
        "foreignField": "guid",
        "as": "resultingStudyGroupsArray"
      }
    },
    { "$unwind": "$resultingStudyGroupsArray" },
    {
      "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "myStudyGroups": { "$addToSet": "$resultingStudyGroupsArray" },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
      }
    }   ]).exec(function(err, results){
    console.log(results);
    return res.json({ studyGroups: results });   }); }
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fetch all the `guid`'s from the *User* model without using aggregate.

```
export function getUserStudyGroups(req, res) {
  User.findOne({ cuid: req.params.cuid }).select('studyGroups').exec((err, studyGroups) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(500).send(err);
    }
    console.log(studyGroups)
    StudyGroup.find({ guid: {$in: studyGroups.studyGroups }}).exec((err, foundGroups) => {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(500).send(err);
      }
        return res.json({ myGroups: foundGroups });
      });
    });
}
```

User and StudyGroup refer to their according model, and `studyGroups.studyGroups` returns an array of strings (the `guid`'s)